# Processing Times for Application to Settle in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

What are the typical processing times for an application to settle in the UK?  I'm specifically interested in applications made by post from within the UK.

For most types of visas, UKVI gives helpful information such as the percent of applications decided within 30, 60, and 90 days.  But for applications to settle from within the UK, [the only information they give](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration/about/about-our-services) is a service promise of 6 months.

A [freedom of information request a few years ago](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/waiting_times_for_settlement_vis) resulted in them disclosing a median processing time of 37 calendar days, and an average time of 47 calendar days.  However, the visa regime has changed significantly since then.  A [more recent similar request](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/current_waiting_times_for_settle) was not successful.

Does anyone have any knowledge of actual processing times?

Comment: It varies depending on the application type, quality of evidence, complications, current backlog of applications, and even political environment. I'm not sure how much more granular you want to be than what you've well researched and found out already.